# Добавить идентификатор для метки (кластера) яндекс карты

Tags: яндекс-карты, кластер

```
Вывожу метки на карту Яндекс следующим образом:

function addMarker(coordin1, coordin2, adres) {
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [coordin1,coordin2],
        {balloonContentHeader: 'Метка'});

        clusterer.add(myPlacemark);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
}

Как узнать, какой идентификатор присвоился метки?
Если он не присвоился, тогда как его присвоить?
```